# How to check exisiting course and save changes in EmployeeCourse table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

**Problem**

update changes (name) in employee table

and changes in courses in table EmployeeCourse in database

in Edit function[HTTP post]

**Detailes**

I have 3 tables Employee,Course,EmployeeCourse

so that when i select employee then edit in courses selected

for this employee by add courses or remove courses

and change in (name)

will save in two tables employee and employee course table

details found in image link

[update courses in employee courses and employee data for employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eMjN.jpg)

**code**

```
public class EditEmployeeVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Courses { get; set; }
    public int[] CourseIds { set; get; }
    public List<CourseVm> ExistingCourses { set; get; }
}

public class CourseVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
in edit function get i pass data to edit view

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
     var vm = new EditEmployeeVm { Id = id };
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            vm.Name = emp.Name;
            vm.ExistingCourses = db.EmployeeCourses
                                    .Where(g => g.EmployeeId == id)
                                    .Select(f => new CourseVm
                                    {
                                        Id = f.Id,
                                        Name = f.Course.CourseName
                                    }).ToList();

            vm.CourseIds = vm.ExistingCourses.Select(g => g.Id).ToArray();
            vm.Courses = db.Courses.Select(f => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                Text = f.CourseName
            }).ToList();

            return View(vm);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)
    {
     what code i write here to update changes in two tables
    employee and employeecourse
course id as array
    }
```

Comment: any one can help me in answering this if possible

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with checkbox  if the employee is taking a course  mark the checkbox like this

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Asignaturas</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var c in cursos) 
        {
            var tomado = false;
            foreach (var c2 in Model.Cursos) 
            {
                if (c.id == c2.id) 
                {
                    tomado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <label><input type="checkbox" @(tomado ? "checked" : "") name="cursos" value="@c.id" /> @c.Nombre</label>
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I leave the blog where you can see more detailed

[Here](http://anexsoft.com/p/82/asp-net-mvc-insertando-actualizando-con-relaciones-de-mucho-a-mucho)

and as for the name you can do a partial view and edit it with ajax

Comment: and in your controller you can recibe  the user and the array of courses
public ActionResult save(string usuario, string[] selected_courses  = null){  }